# Critical point at $ g(x)$

Tags: calculus

If $f(x) > 0$, and $g'(x) = xf(x) - 3f(x)$ what are the critical points of $g(x)$?

For the last two questions I posted, I had an initial solution, but I am not sure how should I approach this one. Any help would be great.

Thanks

Comment: $f(x)=0$ and $x=3$

Comment: If $g(x)$ is continuous and doesn't have vertical asymptote or something!

Comment: Freemind, How did you arrive to this conclusion?

Comment: Do you know the critical point definition? a point in the domain of a particular function $f$ where $f'(x)=0$ or $f'(x)$ doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Just as FreeMind comments: You should firstly be clear to the definition of critical point.

> A point in the domain of a particular function $g(x)$ where $g'(x)=0$ or $g'(x)$ doesn't exist.

Since $g'(x)$  exists and  $g'(x) = xf(x) - 3f(x)$, let $g'(x)=0$. So we have the unique critical point $x=3$, because $f(x)>0$.

May it helps!